# Referencing across files using xr-hyper fails

Tags: cleveref, xr

I saved the following LaTeX code in `test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[My 1st Theorem]\label{thm}
A
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

I ran `lualatex test`. The execution terminated successfully, and the typeset output was:

[image: 1st theorem]

I then saved the following LaTeX code in `test2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[A-]{test}[test.pdf]

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thms.} % singular and plural forms of label

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[My 2nd Theorem]\label{thm}
B
\end{theorem}

\Cref{thm} is an important theorem that can be derived from \cref{A-thm}.

\end{document}
```

I ran `lualatex test2` twice. The executions terminated successfully, and the resulting output was:

[image: 2nd theorem]

**Questions about `test2`'s output**

1. Why does the first reference typeset as *Theorem* rather than *Thm.* as instructed in the preamble?
2. Why is the second reference missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first argument of `\crefname` is wrong, use `theorem` there.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[A-]{test}[test.pdf]

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{theorem}{Thm.}{Thms.} % singular and plural forms of label

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[My 2nd Theorem]\label{thm}
B
\end{theorem}

\Cref{thm} is an important theorem that can be derived from \cref{A-thm}.

\end{document}
```

2. Your external document doesn't load cleveref and so its label is missing. It is also recommended to load hyperref too, without it the link won't work (as there aren't destinations in the target):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}[My 1st Theorem]\label{thm}
A
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding the command `\externaldocument[A-]{test}[test.pdf]` in the 1st part of your answer: I understand the purpose of the `A-` optional argument, and I understand the purpose of the `test.pdf` optional argument. But what is the purpose of the `test` mandatory argument? And why is the `test.pdf` argument optional rather than mandatory?

Comment: The command would make more sense to me if it were written thus: `\externaldocument[A-]{test.pdf}`. What if I use this form? Will it do the same thing as the form used in your 1st answer? If their effects are the same, is there any advantage to using the form in your answer over this shorter form? If their effects are not the same, what are the differences?